# How can I pass an output file from a AWK script to an argument in cat?

Tags: unix, awk

I wish to concatenate file2 with file3 without saving file2 in the disk.

```
awk '...{print}' file1 > file2 

cat file2 file3 > file4
```

How can I do it without saving file2?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a subshell

```
(awk '...{print}' file1; cat file3) > file4
```

Comment: Just tested your suggestion. It works fine. It is handy to know this because I have large amount of outputs and do not have sufficient disk space to save them. Cheers

Comment: You don't have to use a subshell, use braces to group the commands in the current shell: `{ awk '...'; cat file3; } > file4` (the trailing semicolon and the spaces around the braces are required)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [@Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386612/how-can-i-pass-an-output-file-from-a-awk-script-to-an-argument-in-cat/4386686#4386686), but depending on your shell (bash/zsh/...), you could use process substitution:

```
cat <(awk ...) file3 > file4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use just Awk:

```
awk FNR file1 file3> file4
```

This will concenate`file1` and `file3` and will save it to `file4`

Comment: For that matter, you could replace `NFR` with `1`. But it's just doing exactly what `cat` does, without doing any processing of file1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a subshell:

```
awk '...{print}' file1 | cat - file3 > file4
```

or even:

```
awk 'FNR!=NR {print;next} ... {do_stuff}' file1 file3 > file4
```

That will cause file1 to be processed by `do_stuff` and file3 will be passed straight through.